# how to get cpu temperature in c/c++/vb.net/c#?

Tags: .net, wmi

How can I get the cpu temperature using c/c++/vb.net/c# ? I already found this link [Get CPU Temperature in .Net](http://www.developersource.net/DevPage.aspx?ID=11), but I'm not sure if it really works.

Also I would like to know if there is a way other than using wmi queries.

Comment: Did you try the code at the link you provided? Looks like the approach I would take. WMI is designed specifically for this sort of thing...Is there a reason you want to do it differently?

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195112/how-to-get-cpu-temperature

Comment: Well, the duplicate question appears to have the incorrect answer marked as correct. The second answer has a veiled reference to a WMI utility. All in all pretty unhelpful, I'd say.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in your code via WMI. I've found a tool from Microsoft that creates code for it.

> The WMI Code Creator tool allows you to generate VBScript, C#, and VB
>   .NET code that uses WMI to complete a management task such as querying
>   for management data, executing a method from a WMI class, or receiving
>   event notifications using WMI.

You can download it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572).

Comment: @Searush I did install WMI code creator, just wondering how can we use it to get the CPU temperature ?

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear possible to use the **Win32_TemperatureProbe** wmi class, at least when I query it I get nothing back, and this appears to be common.

I found this custom c# driver someone wrote for retrieving the information:

http://temperature.myweb.hinet.net/index_en.htm

It includes the source code.