# CPU Temperature for Linux OS / Intel 64 bit Architecture

Tags: c, linux-kernel, load, cpu, temperature

I have come across several post to read CPU temperature ad fan speed[ [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195112/how-to-get-cpu-temperature), [2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195112/how-to-get-cpu-temperature), but could not find any post for the 64-bit i7 Intel architecture (quad core) using Linux OS. Can any one point to any article and/or source code that can read individual core temperature and possibly fan speed. I have been going through the performance counters in the intel architecture, I find [Chapter 14](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3a-part-1-manual.pdf) to describe the [Thermal Monitors](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/doc/manual/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3b-part-2-manual.pdf) for the thermal status informations. Any sample C code to read these information/ registers will be of great help.

Answer (score 2):

One common way is to read `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp`.

You can take a look at the source code of i3status which is written in C and is able to display the CPU temperature: [print_cpu_temperature.c](http://code.stapelberg.de/git/i3status/tree/src/print_cpu_temperature.c)