# How to get CPU temperature with Open Hardware Monitor?

Tags: c++, windows, cpu, temperature, openhardwaremonitor

So I've been trying to get CPU temperature on windows, msvc, at last I found Libre Hardware Monitor, fork of Open Hardware Monitor.

And someone([Get CPU Temperature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23314886/get-cpu-temperature/72615539#72615539)) said he used lhwm-wrapper(https://gitlab.com/OpenRGBDevelopers/lhwm-wrapper) so it can be used with **c++**.

There is three functions this lhwm-wrapper exports:

```
GetHardwareSensorMap()
//returns a map

GetSensorValue(std::string identifier)
//returns float

SetControlValue(std::string identifier, float value)
//void function
```

So I've been curious about how to use this functions to get CPU heat, I think I should use `GetSensorValue(std::string identifier)` to access but ***I don't know what to input***. Maybe CPU's heat sensor's value I have completely no idea.

I created a visual studio project where I can use lhwm-wrapper, and tried to give some values to `GetSensorValue(std::string identifier)`

like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <lhwm-cpp-wrapper.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << LHWM::GetSensorValue("0");
}
```

whatever I gave as input outputed as 0.

Comment: If you look at [LHWM.cs](https://gitlab.com/OpenRGBDevelopers/lhwm-wrapper/-/blob/master/lhwm-wrapper/LHWM.cs) you see a variable called 'sensors_map'. This variable gets initialized when using the wrapper. Maybe you could try adding a function to the wrapper which prints all the contents of this variable. Because, GetSensorValue uses this 'sensor_map' dictionary.

Comment: @Xander I printed the map, it just gives my pc components. This is the output for CPU:
AMD Ryzen 5 4600H with Radeon Graphics, CPU Core #1, Load, /amdcpu/0/load/1.
I think it only helps to create the map