# C# - How to get the machine information

Tags: c#, .net

Using C#, I am creating a simple application for retrieving the machine information using the C# code itself.

So far, I have found the following libraries to help getting certain information:

- OS, Username, Machine name (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.aspx)
- Network information like the IP Address, DNS (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.aspx)

I still want to figure out how to retrieve the following information:

- Temperature of the CPU
- Battery power of the laptop / mobile device

Kindly share whether they can be achieved using existing .Net libraries or not and how, else please share whether an additional stuff like software or hardware is required.

Thanks.

Comment: I think that you should have a look on Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582(v=vs.85).aspx). Using this feature can help u retrieving a lot of information about the machine. Here is a quick example on how to use it https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2014/08/11/sample-c-code-for-using-the-latest-wmi-classes-to-manage-windows-storage/ If you want to check that you can retrieve using WMI, check this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh830612.aspx

Comment: For temperature of CPU, please refer to:
[how-to-get-cpu-temperature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195112/how-to-get-cpu-temperature)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I made a library for this: https://github.com/Jinjinov/Hardware.Info